# Java OutputStreamWriter default endianness

Tags: java, character-encoding, outputstream, endianness

In Java if I create an `OutputStreamWriter` using a charset of `UTF-16`, does Java prescribe a default endianness (`UTF-16BE` or `UTF-16LE`), or is the default dependent on the underlying operating system.

Note: I've seen others claim that the default is `UTF-16BE`, citing the [`Charset` API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), but my interpretation of said documentation is that it applies to interpretation of a UTF-16 input stream without a BOM, <strike>and says nothing about the required behavior (if any) of `OutputStreamWriter` using UTF-16 in the absence of a specified endianness</strike>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc specifies that using UTF-16:

> When decoding, the UTF-16 charset interprets the byte-order mark at the beginning of the input stream to indicate the byte-order of the stream but defaults to big-endian if there is no byte-order mark; **when encoding, it uses big-endian byte order and writes a big-endian byte-order mark.**

Comment: Wow, I must have been tired this morning and missed that part. Thanks for pointing that out.